# Unrecognized Service ssh when building from source

Tags: 14.04, ssh, openssh, sshd

So I have a web server that is running 14.04LTS because that is the latest Ubuntu Distribution I can have through my VPS. I have been trying to install OpenSSH 7.2p2 via building the source code via the following commands:

```
wget http://mirrors.sonic.net/pub/OpenBSD/OpenSSH/portable/openssh-7.2p2.tar.gz
tar -zxvf openssh-7.2p2.tar.gz
cd openssh-7.2p2
./configure
sudo make
sudo make install
```

And when I type `ssh -V` I get the output: `OpenSSH_7.2p2, OpenSSL 1.0.2h  3 May 2016`, but when I try `service ssh` I get `ssh: unrecognized service`. Any ideas what I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So with the info Jakuje provided I figured out the solution. ***This should only be used if you DO NOT have the option to upgrade to a newer LTS version, but need to upgrade OpenSSH and cannot find a ppa with the build you need.***

First install openssh-server via `sudo apt-get install openssh-server`. After that is installed, copy `/etc/init/ssh.conf` and `/etc/init.d/ssh` to somewhere safe. Now uninstall openssh-server and openssh-client (which openssh-server installed) via `sudo apt-get remove --purge openssh-server` and `sudo apt-get remove --purge openssh-client`. If you plan to use privilege serpartaion follow the instructions here: https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/master/README.privsep. Now do the following:

```
wget http://mirrors.sonic.net/pub/OpenBSD/OpenSSH/portable/openssh-7.2p2.tar.gz
tar -zxvf openssh-7.2p2.tar.gz
cd openssh-7.2p2
./configure --prefix=/usr --sysconfdir=/etc/ssh
sudo make
sudo make install
```

After this, place the files you copied earlier back where you found them. When you restart your system, the service should be recognized and automatically start!

Comment: this would work for my  `copy /etc/init.d/ssh to somewhere safe` https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ur3Pm0E7ALA

Answer (score 0):

You installed the `openssh` binaries, but not its Upstart service (the glue connecting ubuntu and openssh service).

You also probably installed the files with different paths than used in Ubuntu so getting service file ([`/etc/init.d/ssh`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/amd64/openssh-server/filelist)) from Ubuntu wont solve the problem completely (but can give you some guide).

Regardless what makes you install openssh from source, it is almost never a good idea and you would better be with updating your Ubuntu to latest 16.04.

Comment: If I had that option I would, believe me, but my VPS has not made 16.04LTS available yet, and because of their setup (using OpenVZ I believe) upgrading using the console upgrade manager breaks everything (from what I could tell, I think it was a combination of incompatible kernel, which I can't upgrade even through `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`, and something going wrong with the startup services). For the time being, my options are limited to installing openssh from the source, or finding a PPA with an updated openssh build which I could not find.